# Undefined name 'HydratedBlocOverrides'

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc

I am a Beginner in flutter and i was learning hydratedBloc, i imported all the needed dependencies as in the tutorial i was following and i run into a problem where my **HydratedBlocOverrrides.runZoned** is marked as an error
[This is the screenshot containing the error[this is the Bloc_Imports files containg the exported hydratedBloc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDBo3.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVTcR.png)
Why do i have this error?

I tried using HydratedBloc to locally store data,i imported hydratedBloc but this syntax was marked and error "Undefined Name" refering to this **HydratedBlocOverrrides.runZoned**

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be tested by others.
[Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 5):

According to [hydrated_bloc's Changelog](https://pub.dev/packages/hydrated_bloc/changelog) in version 9.0.0. It has removed `HydratedBlocOverrides`

> BREAKING: feat!: **reintroduce HydratedBloc.storage** and **remove HydratedBlocOverrides** (#3479)
> upgrade to bloc: ^8.1.0

Therefore change your code from:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  final storage = await HydratedStorage.build(
      storageDirectory: await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory());
  HydratedBlocOverrides.runZoned(
    () => runApp(const MyApp()),
    storage: storage,
  );
}
```

to

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  HydratedBloc.storage = await HydratedStorage.build(
    storageDirectory: await getTemporaryDirectory(),
  );
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Now it is removed in updated version here is updated way to get this

> Blockquote HydratedBloc.storage = await HydratedStorage.build(
> storageDirectory: await getApplicationCacheDirectory(),
> );

```
 void main() async{
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
 
  HydratedBloc.storage = await HydratedStorage.build(
    storageDirectory: await getApplicationCacheDirectory(),
  );
  
  BlocOverrides.runZoned((() => runApp(const MyApp())),
      blocObserver: MyBlocObserver());
}
```